# [OR-Tools]Minimize "type" of tasks using Python CP-SAT solver

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

i am using OR-Tools CP-SAT solver to produce balanced assignments using the following constraints:

```
model.Add(sum(x[assignee_idx, task] * tasks[task].cost for task in task_idxs) <= average_workload[assignee_idx] + eps_tasks[assignee_idx])

model.Add(sum(x[assignee_idx, task] * tasks[task].cost for task in task_idxs) >= average_workload[assignee_idx] - eps_tasks[assignee_idx])
```

I am minimizing the eps terms to get an optimal solution with tasks assigned as close to the expected average as possible.

Now, in addition i would like to minimize the number of different "types" of tasks that are assigned to an assignee (assumption: each task is of exactly one type).

Very naively i thought additional constraints like this could work, including new eps terms that i could add to the objective terms (still minimizing):

```
model.Add(sum(sum(x[assignee_idx, task] for task in tasks[type]) >= 1 for type in types) <= average_types + eps_task_types)
```

I have read about Channeling and Conditional evaluation, but do not know how this could maybe be applied here?
Does anybody have an idea how this could be approached?

(Described naive approach gives a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'BoundedLinearExpression' - makes sense, but the line was more to outline in pseudo-code what the idea of the additional constraints is)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create 1 Bool var per type.

something like:

```
types_used = []
for type in types:
  type_used = model.NewBoolVar('')
  types_used.append(type_used)

  # link x with type_used.
  all_x = []
  for task in tasks[type]:
    # if one x is active, the type is used.
    model.AddImplication(x[assignee_idx, task], type_used)
    all_x.append(x[assignee_idx])
  # if no x are active, the type_used is false.
  all_x.append(type_used.Not())
  model.AddBoolOr(all_x)

# Constraint the sum of types used.
model.Add(sum(types_used) <= average_types + eps_task_types)
```

note that you can use an alternate code  for the reverse implication.

```
  all_negated_x = []
  for task in tasks[type]:
    # if one x is active, the type is used.
    model.AddImplication(x[assignee_idx, task], type_used)
    all_negated_x.append(x[assignee_idx].Not())
  # if no x are active, the type_used is false.
  model.AddBoolOr(type_used.Not()).OnlyEnforceIf(all_negated_x)
```

Comment: Dear Laurent, thank you very much for your answer! This helps, the seperate bool vars and implication (hadn't come across that one yet) make perfect sense.

However, i do not understand the part with the 'all_x' constraints - can you please expand on why they are needed? 
(I assumed it should be `all_x.append(x[assignee_idx, task].Not())` compared to snippet above)

Comment: There was a bug. I fixed a code and implemented an alternate version.